# What would I measure if I place a relativistic particle on a weighing scale?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, mass, charge, mass-energy

The concept of relativistic mass is considered outdated and when people refer to mass now, it's the invariant or rest mass. If I understand the idea correctly, back in the day people tried to rewrite the relativistic momentum equation - $p=\gamma m v$ - as follows - $p = m_{relativistic} v = \gamma m v$ - to make it look like its conventional form. However, this idea was later dropped and mass is now defined to be $E_{rest}/c^2$. So my question is the following :- If I were to place two conducting plates such that they create a uniform electric field between them, and let a relativistic electron pass through like in the diagram, would the electron follow the same trajectory as an electron with mass equal to the "rest mass" at the same speed?

[image]

What I mean by this is what "mass" should I plug in to the equation: $E q= m a$  or $E q = \gamma m a$?

If it is the latter, would it not be correct to say the mass of the electron is actually larger than when stationary? Or, in other words, if I can put a relativistic electron on a weighing scale, what would it read $m$ or $\gamma m$?

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you want to know. Are you asking whether a faster-moving electron will have a different trajectory in an electric field than a slower-moving electron?

Comment: How do you put a particle moving at a relativistic speed on a scale?

Comment: @Sandejo Depends on what you mean by a "scale", I suppose. If a "scale" just means something that can measure the inertial or gravitational mass of an object, then there are plenty of ways.

Comment: @ Sandejo I used "putting the particle on a scale" figuratively. I am interested in how the particle would behave in the setup that I described. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ Sandejo Scale used to measure inertial mass

Comment: What's wrong with just solving the equations of motion? Electrodynamics in SR is well-known and there are a lot of sources for that.

Comment: @Chandrahas That's the point: we're confused about the setup you described, and what in particular you want to know when you ask "how the particle would behave". It appears that you're wondering whether a faster-moving electron and a slower-moving electron will have different trajectories in an electric field. Is this correct? (The reason this is a confusing setup is because, as written, it doesn't tell you anything about relativity. Electrons with different speeds will have different trajectories, but that's true for both relativity and ordinary Newtonian dynamics.)

Comment: @Chandrahas Typically a "scale" refers specifically to a device that measures gravitational mass, which is another reason people are confused. (Yes, the value of inertial mass and gravitational mass are equivalent according to general relativity, but the two quantities, and how they are measured, are still very conceptually different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the part of this question that's unambiguous, which is: what is the relativistic equivalent of $F=ma$?

The answer to this is:

$$\vec{F}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$$

Substituting in $\vec{p}=\gamma m\vec{v}$ and applying the product rule, we have that, for a body of constant rest mass:

$$\vec{F}=\frac{d\gamma}{dt}m\vec{v}+\gamma m \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$

A bit of algebraic manipulation will show you that:

$$\vec{F}=\gamma^3m\vec{a}_\parallel+\gamma m\vec{a}_\perp$$

where $\vec{a}_\parallel$ is the part of the accleration vector that's parallel to the direction of travel and $\vec{a}_\perp$ is the acceleration vector that's perpendicular to the direction of travel.

Comment: So perpendicular to motion, the inertia is lower than in the parallel direction? Also, the force would still be $E q$ right?

Comment: @Chandrahas It can be thought of that way, yes. In the rest frame of the electric field, the force would be $Eq$, pointing along the electric field. Note: as soon as the particle starts accelerating in the field, the force is _not_ perfectly perpendicular to the direction of travel anymore, so both components of acceleration are important.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that, at relativistic speeds, mass is not the inertia of an object?

Comment: @Chandrahas Well, that depends on a particular definition of "inertia". One could say instead that inertia is just mass, but the _relationship between inertia and force is different_ at relativistic speeds.

Comment: @Chandrahas This is very similar to the modern way of teaching about mass: the mass of an object is always the same, but the _relationship between velocity and momentum_ changes at relativistic speeds.